# ckeditor 5 plugins not working with svelte

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, svelte, rollupjs, ckeditor5

1. I'm trying to get ckeditor with html support to work within svelte.

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
    import { FullPage } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-html-support';
    export let text = ""; 
    onMount( () => {
        ClassicEditor.create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {plugins : [FullPage]})
        .then( editor => {
            console.log( editor );
            editor.setData( text );
            editor.model.document.on( 'change:data', () => {
                text = editor.getData();
            } );
        } )
        .catch( error => {
            console.error( error );
        } );
    });
</script>

<textarea id='editor'></textarea>
```

#### ✔️ Expected result

I would expect the above code to result in a ckeditor instance with html support.

#### ❌ Actual result

my js build using rollup gives me the below error

```
(!) Circular dependencies
node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/view/position.js -> node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/view/treewalker.js -> node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/view/position.js
node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/view/documentselection.js -> node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/view/selection.js -> node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/view/documentselection.js
node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/model/position.js -> node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/model/treewalker.js -> node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/model/position.js
...and 4 more
created static/js/bundle.js in 13.7s
```

#### ❓ Possible solution

If I remove the line as well as FullPage from the plugins array then I have no issues.

```
import { FullPage } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-html-support';
```

The editor will be instantiated.
this could be an issue with my rollup.config.js --

```
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import css from "rollup-plugin-css-only";
import autoPreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy';
import scss from 'rollup-plugin-scss';
import polyfillNode from 'rollup-plugin-polyfill-node';
import svg from 'rollup-plugin-svg';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;
export default {
    input: 'svelte-components/src/main.js', // (1)
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: 'static/js/bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        svg(),
        css({ output: "extra_bundle.css" }),
        scss({
            fileName: "bootstrap.css",
            failOnError: true,
            runtime: require("sass"),
          }),
        svelte({
            // enable run-time checks when not in production
            dev: !production,
            // we'll extract any component CSS out into
            // a separate file - better for performance
            css: css => {
                css.write('bundle.css'); // (3)
            }
        }),
        // If you have external dependencies installed from
        // npm, you'll most likely need these plugins. In
        // some cases you'll need additional configuration -
        // consult the documentation for details:
        // https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs
        resolve({
            browser: true,
            dedupe: ['svelte']
        }),
        commonjs(),
        // In dev mode, call `npm run start` once
        // the bundle has been generated
        !production && serve(),

        // Watch the `public` directory and refresh the
        // browser on changes when not in production
        !production && livereload('svelte-components'), // (4)

        // If we're building for production (npm run build
        // instead of npm run dev), minify
        production && terser(),
        copy({
            targets: [
                { src: 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', dest: 'static/js' },              
            ],
            verbose: true,
        }),
        polyfillNode(), // Add this plugin
        terser()
    ],
    watch: { 
        clearScreen: false
    }
};

function serve() {
    let started = false;

    return {
        writeBundle() {
            if (!started) {
                started = true;

                require('child_process').spawn('npm', ['run', 'start', '--', '--dev'], {
                    stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit'],
                    shell: true
                });
            }
        }
    };
}
```

If you'd like to see this fixed sooner, add a  reaction to this post.